# Align "td"s in a table

Tags: css, asp.net, html, html-table

I have a design like this.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td style="width: 50%">
  <table id="table1">
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   .
   .
   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td style="width: 50%">
  <table id="table2">
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here Table1 is shorter than table2 as there are fewer rows in table1, As a result, I am getting the table in middle of the main td, not at top. I cant give padding-bottom or margin bottom for table1 as for some conditions table1 may grow longer. I need to get the table1 at top. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `td { vertical-align: top; }` in css should do the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/julysfx/peh32tya/

Comment: this can align all the td's to top :)

Comment: yeh I thought he wanted all the td's to the top anyway but yeh your solution looks better to be honest

Comment: your's it good too, but if already is using CSS, better to add a class for specific td's.

Answer (score 2):

**Add valign="top" for first or both td's.**

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
 <td valign="top" style="width: 50%">
  <table id="table1">
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   .
   .
   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td valign="top" style="width: 50%">
  <table id="table2">
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

User `vertical-align:top;` in `td`. Short and Simple